# JSON.stringify an Array of HTML Elements/Strings

Tags: javascript, html, json

How can we convert this Javascript Array  `[li.one, li.one, li.one, li.two, li.two, li.two]` into a JSON array using JSON.stringify?

Using the following Javascript:

```
    var stringsToStringify = $('.one, .two'),
            stringArray = []

    $.each(stringsToStringify, function (i, v) {
        stringArray[i] = v
    })

    console.log(stringArray)
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(stringArray)
    console.log(jsonString)
    console.log(JSON.parse(jsonString))
```

Returns:

```
 [li.one, li.one, li.one, li.two, li.two, li.two]

[{"jQuery110203514890133216494":1},{"jQuery110203514890133216494":2},{"jQuery110203514890133216494":3},{"jQuery110203514890133216494":4},{"jQuery110203514890133216494":5},{"jQuery110203514890133216494":6}]

[Object { jQuery110203514890133216494=1}, Object { jQuery110203514890133216494=2}, Object { jQuery110203514890133216494=3}, Object { jQuery110203514890133216494=4}, Object { jQuery110203514890133216494=5}, Object { jQuery110203514890133216494=6}]
```

If we change the `stringArray` from `[]` to `{}` the following is returned:

```
 [li.one, li.one, li.one, li.two, li.two, li.two]

[{"jQuery110207305097851789301":1},{"jQuery110207305097851789301":2},{"jQuery110207305097851789301":3},{"jQuery110207305097851789301":4},{"jQuery110207305097851789301":5},{"jQuery110207305097851789301":6}]

[Object { jQuery110207305097851789301=1}, Object { jQuery110207305097851789301=2}, Object { jQuery110207305097851789301=3}, Object { jQuery110207305097851789301=4}, Object { jQuery110207305097851789301=5}, Object { jQuery110207305097851789301=6}]
```

The desired result is to have `[li.one, li.one, li.one, li.two, li.two, li.two]` "stringified" into a JSON Array.

This looks like a circular reference. What is the best way to supply the array of html elements to `JSON.stringify`?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7jm3c3r/)

Comment: What do you expect it to show? The plain HTML text?

Comment: `$('.one, .two')` returns an array of jQuery objects.

Comment: Yes, the plain HTML text `JSON.stringify`'d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.one, .two')` returns a jQuery object containing references to whichever DOM elements have those two classes, it doesn't return an array of strings. So within your `$.each()`, the `v` parameter is not a string, it is a DOM element. If you want the HTML text (or just the text) of that element use `$(v).html()` or `$(v).text()`:

```
var stringArray = [];
$('.one, .two').each(function(i, v) {
  stringArray.push( $(v).html() );
});
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(stringArray);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/stL1hz9t/

Note that I've used [`$('.one, .two').each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) rather than the [generic iterator `$.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), because you want to loop over the items in a jQuery object. (`$.each()` will work, but it adds just that slight bit of extra complexity to your code.) You don't need your `stringsToStringify` variable (which as I mentioned above doesn't actually contain strings).

Or you can use the [`.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map) to simplify the code somewhat:

```
var stringArray = $('.one, .two').map(function (i, v) {
                    return $(v).html();
                  }).get();
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(stringArray);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/stL1hz9t/1/

Answer (score 1):

The array you created only returns jQuery object that reference the original DOM. To output the DOM element do the following:

```
$.each(stringsToStringify, function (i, v) {
    stringArray[i] = $("<p>").append($(v).clone()).html();
})
```

Note this whole `$("<p>").append($(v).clone()).html()` construction creates a clone of the original element, then appends the clone to a new parent and then gets the HTML from that. If you simply call `.html()` you will only get the content of the `<li>` tag, not the tag itself.

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/f0xchck6/